# Set Preferences in android using shared preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I trying to build a setting page for a test app. In code, I am using PreferenceActivity class. When I set some setting from settings page, I am able to retrive that value anywhere in the app using following method.

```
SharedPreferences SP;
SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String username = SP.getString("username", "bob");
```

Also I am able to set the key value from anywhere in code. Like the following method after providing the context.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
edit.putString("username", "bob");
edit.commit();
```

The problem is, when I open settings page, "username" field is not updated with "bob". I want to reflect the SharedPreferences variable's changed values in the settings Activity which is the extend PreferenceActivity working on preferences.xml. I am populating the preferences like below.

Settings.java

```
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        PrefManager prefManager;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
        android:key="username"
        android:summary="Please provide your username">
    </EditTextPreference>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: can you please post your code here

Comment: You are setting `"username"` and getting `"userName"`

Comment: @Sharj Sorry. That was a typo.

Comment: You want to show the updated value in edittext pre-filled, if user has saved some data before?

Comment: I want to reflect the `username`'s changed vlaue in the settings page, whenever it gets changed in code. (Assume that I am randomly changing the username in app from code) Just want to reflect it in settings page.

Comment: can you get those values stored in preferences?

Answer (score 0):

i'm confused why you are use different method from mine ,try like this:

```
//get value
sp = getSharedPreferences("filename",MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.getString("username","bob");

//save value
sp = getSharedPreferences("filename",MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit= sp.edit();
edit.putString("username", "bob");
edit.commit();
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same. My username value is getting updated. But How can I reflect the same thing in preferences.xml for the PreferenceActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        PreferenceManager prefManager;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
            final Preference pref = findPreference("username");
            pref.setSummary("your value which you alradey saved in preferences");
            pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    // do whatever you want with new value

                    // true to update the state of the Preference with the new value
                    // in case you want to disallow the change return false

                    pref.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Wagon (https://github.com/beplaya/Wagon).  Super super simple annotations for shared preferences.

```
...
@Crate(key = "myPreferenceCrate", preference = true)
public CrateExample crate;
@WoodBox(key = "myPreferenceString", preference = true)
public String value;
...
wagon.pack(getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE));
...
wagon.unpack(getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE));
...
```